# How can I rewrite localhost to a fakeserver?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a root folder htaccess containing my htaccess file and another folder,me containing my index.php file ..I want to use url rewrite such that when I access `http://localhost/htaccess/me/index.php , it transforms the url to http://fakeserver/htaccess/me/index.php..`

Drupal does such a thing..

I want to do this transformation such that the fakeserver is not a real server just that I rewrite the localhost to fakeserver

Comment: If you're using a Windows computer you can edit the `hosts` file. I don't know if this works on a Unix computer..

Comment: @WouterJ: `%WINDIR%\drivers\etc\hosts` originates from `/etc/hosts` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new site configuration at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/fakeserver`
(Note you will need to create file `fakeserver`)

Inside that, add this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
DocumentRoot /var/www/
ServerName fakeserver
</VirtualHost>
```

Enable it, from your terminal

```
sudo a2ensite fakeserver
```

Restart apache to reflect changes

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up a Virtual Host. Give a look at these examples, from the Apache HTTPD Docs:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html